# Map Reduce - Maven (How it works?)

Tags: java, maven, mapreduce

I am new to Maven and Java. I created a simple map-reduce program in Eclipse and used maven to specify the dependencies. (I specified the hadoop dependencies in POM.XML). It downloaded all dependecies and I can see all of them in maven dependecies. Then I created a JAR and ran it in the cluster. Everything is working fine.  But when I unzip the JAR file, I am not seeing any dependency jars from Hadoop inside my JAR? Then I am confused how it worked ?  As per my understanding you need all JARS distributed.  Please teach me.

thanks,
John

Comment: Actually it depends. If you plan to distribute a single JAR, then, yes, you need a jar-with-dependencies. If you can distirbute a _maven artifact_, then dependencies of the artifact are handled by maven automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To build a jar with dependencies included, you have to configure `maven-assembly-plugin`. Take a look at this:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>attached</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.example.package.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Source-Version>${build-version}</Source-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop loads jar files while running jobs using the location specified in HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

It is located in file conf/hadoop_env.sh file:

```
# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="<extra_entries>:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"
```

Comment: As I stated in my question, the JAR I created doesn't had any of the dependecies , still it worked well. Thats why I got puzzled?